# c - expecting struct pointer but getting struct and the reverse

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct

I am attempting to call on function "play game" from main, with play game having input type 'struct player'. However, I am getting error:

```
game.h:18:17: note: expected ‘struct player *’ but argument is of type ‘struct player’
struct player * play_game(struct player * first, struct player * second);
reversi.c:47:4: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘play_game’
*winner = play_game( first , second );
```

With the error being thrown out for argument 2.

When I switch the argument type to being a pointer I get:

```
reversi.c:47:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct player’ from type ‘struct player *’
*winner = play_game( first , second );
```

I've looked around, but there doesn't seem to be much on this, and it's usually related to the .h file itself, while I am almost certain that the error must involve the line: "*winner = play_game( first , second );" (the other lines here were provided)

I've also tried changing all the pointers, even when to the point that if it had worked I would have been lost, but haven't gotten anywhere except getting variations on the same error.

I've trimmed the code down for posting, but it does still produce the same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAMELEN 20

struct player * play_game(struct player * first, struct player * second) ;

enum cell
{
        BLANK, RED, BLUE
};

struct player
{
    char name[NAMELEN + 1];
    enum cell token;
    unsigned score;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct player first, second, *winner = NULL;
    enter code here
    *winner = play_game( first , second );

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


struct player * play_game(struct player * first, struct player * second) 
{

    return first;

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a thing and a pointer to a thing?

Comment: @immibis Not as well as I should, I suspect. I'm going to go back over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call musts to look like

```
winner = play_game( &first , &second );
```

Comment: Thank you; I thought it might involve adding pointers inside the function, but I didn't think to remove the one from before winner.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the function as taking arguments as call by reference. So you  need to call the function with the arguments [call by reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm).

```
 winner = play_game( &first , &second );
```

And remove the `*` while assigning the return value into winner variable.

Comment: This is not "calling by reference", it is a normal call with pointer values.